# Record Calls, Messages & Video using Skype For Web SDK

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, skype-bots, microsoft-skype-bot

Everyone,

Was searching over the net but didn't find any article describing the information. Can any please tell me whether I can record calls, videos & messages using Skype For Web SDK ?

Sorry I didn't demonstrated any code cause I didn't find anything so Keep it short and simple.

Comment: I also have this question: can I record calls, videos & messages using Skype For Web SDK ?

Comment: @Tony I am still waiting for the answer If you find it then pls enlighten me as well !!!

Comment: As of now Skype for web SDK is not supporting Audio/Video recording. I am also waiting for that.  If any one had found any alternative solution then pls share it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Skype for web SDK team has any intention to provide `Recording` or `Cognitive analytics` ability to Web SDK in the near future. So i decided to go with alternative ways.
After a lot of research, i have decided to use `Skype Media bot` along with `Skype Web SDK` to record audio and video conversations.

1. Create a Skype Media Bot and add Skype for Business as channel.
2. Register this bot with Skype for Business online ( Only Tenant Administrator can do that)
3. Make sure in each conference, this Skype Bot is also invited by default. So this bot is a participant in each conference call. It records audio and video.
4. Skype Bot has simple interface to Record, Respond, Convert audio to text and many more features.

Github samples can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples)

Skype Bot framework has `NodeJS` and `C#` APIs.